# Force resize the window of a default Mac app (Preview) on Monterey

Tags: macos

after updating to Monterey I noticed that you cannot resize the preview app after a certain width.

I used to be able to have 30% screen size dedicated to a book, 70% dedicated to my note taking app in the full screen split view. Now it is more like 50-50 which is really annoying as I don't have enough space to properly display the other app.

So the question is, is there a way to force an application to have a certain width and height, even if the application doesn't want to comply?

In response to user3439894, this is what happens when you try grabbing the sizing bar between the two panes, the arrow clearly tells you you can go in only one direction.
[image]
You can tell from the MacBook writing above that it is actually taking >50% of the available screen real estate.

Comment: With **Preview** opened with a **PDF** _document_ and in **Split Screen** on **macOS Monterey** I have no trouble resizing the _window_ to ~25% (maybe even less) of the width of my **display** by grabbing the _sizing bar_ between the two _panes_.

Comment: @user3439894 I have updated the question